# Variant Half-Elf: is this meant to be Keen Senses AND another trait?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, racial-traits, proficiency, half-elf

The *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* says:

> Some half-elves in Faerûn have a racial trait in place of the Skill Versatility trait. If your DM allows it, your half-elf character can forgo Skill Versatility and instead take the elf trait Keen Senses ***or*** a trait based on your elf parentage:

Emphasis mine. The traits based on parentage are things like swim speed for aquatic elves or magic for drow parents. But here's the thing. Skill Versatility is

> You gain proficiency in two skills of your choice.

while Keen Senses is

> You have proficiency in the Perception skill.

Why would one ever pick Keen Senses over Skill Versatility (with Perception *and* another skill)? Is this a design oversight, or a typo where it's meant to be "and", or is there something about these traits that I'm missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The Keen senses option is indeed inherently weaker

Your analysis regarding the Keen senses is correct - it gives you proficiency in a single particular skill when you could have proficiency in two skills of your choice. This issue is known yet uncorrected: In a 2015 [tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/664308174560690176) DnD 5e's lead rules developer Jeremy Crawford acknowledges it as follows:

> The half-elf's Keen Senses option in the SCAG is, alas, superfluous. Take one of the juicy options below it.

**This confirms that it indeed  is an "or", not an "and".**

The most recent errata for [Player's Handbook](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) and [SCAG](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf) contain no mention on changing these rules, so until further revisions you can treat taking Keen senses instead of the Skill versatility as a valid, if nonsensical option of the game.